# Only local branch

Tags: mercurial

I want to have local branch in my cloned repository that will not exist in main repository. To do this I create branch named "new_branch", develop and commit to it. Sometimes I make commites to default branch and after that I make "push -b default" that the branch "new_branch" not appeared in main repository. After the development in "new_branch" finished I make merge to default branch and I want to make push for default branch "push -b default". I get message "abort: push creates new remote branches: new_branch! (use 'hg push --new-branch' to create new remote branches)". Can I have a only local branch in Mercurial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

- [LocalBranch Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/LocalbranchExtension) (only [Tim Lee fork](https://bitbucket.org/timlee/mercurial-extensions-localbranch) seems to work with current Mercurial)
- MQ (and push **without** `--mq` option)

Answer (score 0):

[Phases](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Phases) can be used for this in modern Mercurial:

```
# hg phase --secret -r 7::10
```

Will mark changes 7 through 10 as secret, as so they won't be pushed, pulled, cloned, etc.

Comment: That won't solve his problem which is that he wants to merge that branch into default without having to push the branch itself.

Comment: Ahh, I missed that. That would change my response to "Don't do that! The history is valuable"

Answer (score 0):

Once you create a branch using [`hg branch`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/branch), it is a permanent part of the changeset.  It will always require you to push using the `--new-branch` option.  You cannot strip the branch name without modifying history.

If you want give a local name to a branch that does not get propagated when you push, then you should use [`hg bookmark`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/bookmarks) instead.